# How do I use Backbone on multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I am trying to use Backbone to make different views/models for different html pages, but I want to be able to separate the models and views if possible without making it an SPA... Anyone have any clue as to how I would go about this? To make it more "answerable" maybe this question can be answered - How do I use require.js and backbone.js without making it an SPA... how do I layout the page because I know this line gets added to the html page to call require:

```
<script data-main="js/mainU.js" src="js/libs/require.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone was designed for single page apps. On frameworks website it's demonstrated on a lot of  examples. But if you want to do so just write more single page apps and load the required Backbone files inside that apps.